# REST Request from multiple clients, collect all requests per second basis, process them in bulk & send response back to each clients

Tags: java, rest

We are having a web server which receives 100s of client requests every seconds.

1. Need to collect all REST request from clients per second basis.
2. For collected requests, prepare bulk request to Elasticsearch & get the response.
3. Parse Elasticsearch response & prepare individual responses for each REST clients.
4. Send each response to REST clients.

I can take care of Elasticsearch bulk request & need help in creating a REST API which solves above stated problem.

Currently, for each client request, server is making a single Elasticsearch call would be very expensive and to avoid it, needed a solution.

Comment: You'll need to create some thread-safe way to collect those requests, executes a query every so often, then lets the callers know their answer is ready. Such a system can be designed in many ways, which is why I voted to close as Too broad.

Comment: A solution may also be to put all the request in a database and have a scheduled job that run each X time and collect a lot of request from db to be taken and worked. Needs other hacks also.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, there are multiple possible solutions, however, anyway the general approach is to store requests in a thread-safe manner; schedule a job in a separate thread at a desired rate capable of bulk load stored data; notify a request handler in some way when bulk load is complete.

In some more details it could be done as follows:

1. For each request create a `CompletableFuture` and put in along with received data in an a thread-safe collection. For example, `ArrayBlockingQueue<DataAndFutureContainer>` or `ConcurrentHashMap<DataToLoad, CompletableFuture>`
2. Schedule a job at a desired rate via `@Scheduled` (if using Spring) or `Executors.newSingleThreadScheduledExecutor().scheduleAtFixedRate()`
3. That job should retrieve (for example via `ArrayBlockingQueue.poll()` or `ConcurrentHashMap.remove()`) all data **available at the moment**, do bulk load (or whatever you want), and fulfil the related `CompletableFuture` via `.complete()` with result of bulk load (or whatever)
4. Request handler, which have created that futures in step 1 waits on it by `future.get()`, thus gets the result of a bulk load.

Also, some optimisations is available depending on your framework. For example, with Spring you could return [DeferredResult](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-deferred-result) from request handler and use instead of `CompletableFuture`. If you are using Spring WebFlux, you could return `Mono.fromFuture()`

Thats a brief description of a approach, be careful in details.